# Can I update database with modifications done to class for existing database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a `master-details` form in MVC using an existing database. I followed a YouTube video tutorial, but there are differences between my model table and the steps demonstrated in the video. I want to update the database table to match my model. When I create the EF models from the database, the code looks like this:

```cs
public partial class DAILY_REPORT
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public DAILY_REPORT()
    {
        this.employees = new HashSet<employee>();
    }
            
    public int REPORT_ID { get; set; }
    public string hospital_name { get; set; }
    public string DAY_NAME { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime REPORT_DATE { get; set; }
    public string REPORT_TIME { get; set; }
    public int CHK_REASON { get; set; }
    public string ACTION_TAKEN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LAB_ITEMS_COMPLETED { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MISSING_ITEMS { get; set; }
    public string ITEMS_DETAILS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LAB_MACHINE_TEST { get; set; }
    public string MACHINE_ACTION { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BLOOD_BANK_AVAILABLE { get; set; }
    public string BLOOD_BANK_DETAILS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PLAZMA_AVAILABLE { get; set; }
    public string PLAZMA_DETAILS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GROUPS_AVAILABLE { get; set; }
    public string GROUPS_DETAILS { get; set; }
    public string BLOOD_ACTION { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DIFF_AVAILABLE { get; set; }
    public string DIFF_REASON { get; set; }
    public string LAB_MANAGER { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> user_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> hospital_no { get; set; }
        
    public virtual sys_users sys_users { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<employee> employees { get; set; }
}
```

I need to update the class and remove `ICollection` and add this line:

```cs
public virtual List<employee> employees { get; set; } = new List<employee>();
```

However, when I do this, the `master-details` form does not save the details. If I update the model from the database, the `List` is removed, and `ICollection` is added back.

The YouTube video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoLaynKMOoc).

How do I save my model permanently to the database and keep the `List<employee>`?

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have your model you should use Code First Migrations to update the database schema to match the model.

> Code First Migrations is the recommended way to evolve your application's database schema if you are using the Code First workflow. Migrations provide a set of tools that allow creating an initial database that works with your EF model, generating migrations to keep track of changes you make to your EF model, and keeping your database up to date with those changes.

Since you are starting with an existing database, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database?source=recommendations) is a handy doc for proceeding with migrations.

Comment: can you add the steps how to do migration without affecting the existing database and only update the  table DAILY_REPORT to be same as class ? thank you

Comment: Migrations will update the whole database to match the model. The link I included has the needed steps. If you absolutely have to only modify one of the tables, you will have to resort to doing it manually with SQL.

Comment: actually what I need to change public virtual ICollection<employee> employees { get; set; }       which is appeared after I update the model from the database to  public virtual List<employee> employees { get; set; } = new List<employee>();  how can I make the List permanent in the database and model class , If I make later update model from database always show List<> and not ICollection ?